# Phpmyadmin import - change in database size and number of records?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I imported a database using a sql file on 1and1.com... The end message from the host is

'Your SQL query has been executed successfully:
The content of your file has been inserted.'

However, the size of the database is lesser as well as the number of records are less in comparison to the old database when viewed through phpmyadmin.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you do lots of inserting and deleting, the database gets to be bigger than it should be. If you backup and then restore it, you are compacting the space used.

About the row numbers, if your tables are `innodb`, then the number of records is approximate.

How much of a difference are we talking about? Can you post specific numbers?

Comment: i just noticed the records lost are for the tables that have engine type as HEAP...

Comment: You still have access to the old database, right? If you do SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLE>; -- in the old and in the new, do you get different numbers?